# wordpress plugin error on the server

Tags: php, wordpress

i wrote a plugin and it successfully works on my localhost.But when i install it my server and want to activate it fails.

*Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.*

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/ozcanco/public_html/said/wp-content/plugins/Archive/my-plugin.php on line 22

But when i run this plugin on my local it successfully works.By the way my wordpress versions are same,on local and server.How come this happen?

The line 22 is like that:

```
   add_action('loop_start', function($query) use ($allContent){
```

Comment: check if you are using a different version of PHP. Maybe the PHP on your server does not support what you are trying to do. I normally only add the name of the callback function as the second parameter of the add_action() function. eg: add_action('loop_start', 'callback_function');.

Comment: What version of PHP is your server running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That inline function you have is called an anonymous function, or a closure. Closures only became part of PHP in version 5.3, so if your servier is running 5.2 or lower it will not support them.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

If upgrading the server is not an option, then as krike suggested in the comment, you could use a callback function instead:

```
add_action('loop_start', 'loopStartCallback');

function loopStartCallback($query) {
    global $allContent;
    // body of the closure goes here
}
```

Comment: but with your method how can i use my other variable? $allContent?

Comment: Use can use the `global` keyword to make your `$allContent` variable appear in the scope of the callback. I really would recommend updating the PHP version on the sever if you can though. 5.2 is deprecated and has not been patched in 2 years.

Comment: okay i understand,but my script should work with all the servers,shouldn't it?So i should write a portable code.Am i wrong?

Comment: In the case of Wordpress, the minimum supported version is 5.2.4, so you should probably use that as a baseline when developing plugins. For other applications, you might have to make that decision based on features that you consider a must have versus the installed versions of your customers. You are right in that you should make this 5.2 compatible, but please consider updating your server if you can :)

Comment: Okay thanks for your reply,i will upgrade my server as soon as possible :)